# Generic Class method forName

Tags: java

I'm getting the following compilation error:

```
Tester.java:10: unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                Class stringClass = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
```

with this code:

```
class Tester {
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        Class stringClass = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
    }
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: Ah, you're going to love checked exceptions.

Comment: Get yourself a good IDE and they'll fix stuff like this up for you faster than you could have typed it yourself to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

This is both odd and somewhat vague. Yes you must catch ClassNotFoundException since forName throws it or let it bubble up the stack...

```
class Tester{

    public static void main(String [ ] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class stringClass = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
    }
}
```

or

```
class Tester{

    public static void main(String [ ] args) 
    {
        try {
            Class stringClass = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { /* do something with it here */ }
    }
}
```

This is true for all checked exceptions.

Comment: *Checked* exceptions I think you mean. Note that unchecked (runtime) exceptions can also be caught, but you should probably have a good reason for doing this.

Comment: Fixed on the *checked* comment. And yes I know that you can catch unchecked runtime exceptions but given the nature of the question I felt it better to give a simple answer than a overly complex yet more correct one.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Class.forName()` you need to catch or throw the exception that happens when the class is not found on the classpath.

Here's an example of throwing the exception (since it is unlikely that `String` wont be found)

```
public static void main(String [ ] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
  Class stringClass = Class.forName("java.lang.String");



}
```

If you are doing this for a class that may not be on the classpath, you should surround the call with `try...catch` blocks.

Comment: Problem is the class should be found on the class path >,>.  String is a known class